# python bulk insert: getting Error ORA-01438

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Have table with NUMBER, while perform .executemany ( INS, [ data ] )
getting Error ORA-01438.
Same if I inserting single record. I loop the record and found the one that fail cx_Oracle.
it's type is: NUMBER(19,4)

Suspected value: **1000000000000000.0**

Any idea ?..

Answer (score 2):

It is about *scale* and *precision*.

Column you declared is `NUMBER (19, 4)` which means that it accepts numeric values up to `19` digits in length, out of which `4` are reserved for decimals, which also means that there are `19 - 4 = 15` digits available for the whole number.

Value you tried to put in there is

```
1000000000000000.0
12345678901234567890
         10    ^    20
               |
             16 digits of the whole number
```

As `16` digits is larger that max allowed `15`, your code failed.

---

This is what you have:

```
SQL> create table test (val number (19, 4));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1000000000000000.0);
insert into test values (1000000000000000.0)
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

If the column was declared as `(20, 4)`, it would be OK as you'd then have `16` digits for the whole number:

```
SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test (val number (20, 4));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1000000000000000.0);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, declare it just as `NUMBER` and it'll let you insert maximum allowed scale and precision, with no constraints.

Comment: You right, the problem is , that in source Table, the value is: 999999999999999.990000 , I am fetching the value using <cursor>.execute.fetchall() --> and getting the value: 1000000000000000.0

Answer (score 2):

Littlefoot explained your insert issue. I will explain your fetch issue! If you use the default conversion to float, you are limited to 15-16 digits of precision -- and so rounding takes place upon fetch. In order to preserve the precision you need to use the `decimal.Decimal` type. That can done with a type handler or (in python-oracledb) with a simple switch. The following samples demonstrate this:

### cx_Oracle

```py
import cx_Oracle as oracledb

def output_type_handler(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == oracledb.NUMBER:
        return cursor.var(decimal.Decimal, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

conn = oracledb.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWORD, dsn=DSN)
conn.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select number_val from my_table")
```

### python-oracledb

```py
import oracledb

oracledb.defaults.fetch_decimals = True

conn = oracledb.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWORD, dsn=DSN)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select number_val from my_table")
```